# -bash: unalias: emacs: not found

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, alias

I followed some advice on how to remove an alias and run unalias on it. Now every time I open up a shell I get this message :

```
-bash: unalias: emacs: not found
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you please share with us the advice that you followed?

Comment: Have you looked in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bash_login`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you've put `unalias emacs` in a script that runs each time you log on - perhaps in `~/.bashrc`.  Each time you log in, it's trying to run the unalias command when the alias has already been removed.  Try removing this command from any startup scripts and see if that fixes your problem.

If you can't find where you put the `unalias` command, you can try grep'ing through your file system, but it may take a long time: `grep -rn / -e "unalias emacs" 2>/dev/null`

Happy hunting!

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me! Fixed it!!